# IdentityServer invalid tokens cause incorrect Windows Auth NTLM 401 responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, windows-authentication, identityserver4

I have Identity Server on .net Core 2.0 running a resource owner password grant type via the following in-memory client:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "myclient",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    ClientSecrets = {new Secret("AAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE".Sha256())},
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "spa"
    }
}
```

I then tie this to JWT tokens via authentication for Core:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
```

And for IdentityServer:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = serverUrl;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;                    
    options.ApiName = "spa";   
});
```

This works great, but I wanted to add in Windows Auth which I did by following the IdentityServer quickstart at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html.

The `Login()` method then checks a custom viewmodel for whether SSO is in use (determined earlier based on the return URL), and chooses to use `ExternalLogin()` or the default resource owner view. This works fine, and both user credential and Windows Auth logins succeed, with Windows Auth providing the access token back to the client. These access tokens are then used to access the resources.

The problem comes when an invalid bearer access token is sent back up to the server (expiry or manual manipulation). This request fails and the server issues a `401 Unauthorized` response.

Normally this would be okay, as the `WWW-Authenticate` header would be set to `Bearer` along with some error info which could be processed client-side. But iff Windows Auth is enabled in IIS, this header is returned as:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

This in turn causes the browser to pop up the standard credentials entry box, and can't be captured in the front end.

I and others haven't been able to find where these headers are being issued from, as they are occurring without Windows Auth being selected. My best guess is that within the black box of IdentityServer, it's refusing the invalid access token and the server is assuming that the Windows Auth has failed and needs to be reattempted. Why these headers then make it all the way to the browser I'm not sure.

Breakpointing various elements within the code don't yield anything; everything either isn't hit because it's beyond the authentication, or is hit after the browser displays the credentials entry.

Does anyone have an idea where this is coming from, and how I could tame it?

Comment: Im just curious in your client app If  Im not mistaken aren't you suppose to pass the client secret. ex `options.ClientSecret ="AAAAAAA-B ....."`.